# How Do I know on which line I clicked on in a LineCollection?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to know on which line I clicked on in a pick_event from a LineCollection.
Usually I plot signals line by line and I can access to each line information through event.artist._label but in the case of LineCollection, this is not that simple.
If I click on the second segment, I would like to find a variable that contains 1 for instance.
Is there a way to do that?

Here's a minimal example:

```
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand

def onpick1(event):
    print('event')
    if isinstance(event.artist, LineCollection):
        print('LineCollection')
        thoselines = event.artist
        print('Which line did I clicked on ? ')

def linecoll(N):
    x = np.random.rand(N, 3)
    y = np.random.rand(N, 3)
    C = np.random.rand(N, 3)
    L = [str(i) for i in range(N)]
    data = np.stack((x, y), axis=2)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick1)
    lines = ax.add_collection(LineCollection(data,colors=C ))
    lines.set_picker(2)
    lines.labels = L
    plt.show()

linecoll(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html#simple-picking-example), you can use `event.ind`:

```
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand

def onpick1(event):
    print('event')
    if isinstance(event.artist, LineCollection):
        print('LineCollection')
        thoselines = event.artist
        print('Which line did I clicked on ? ')
        print(event.ind)  # <- HERE

def linecoll(N):
    x = np.random.rand(N, 3)
    y = np.random.rand(N, 3)
    C = np.random.rand(N, 3)
    L = [str(i) for i in range(N)]
    data = np.stack((x, y), axis=2)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick1)
    lines = ax.add_collection(LineCollection(data,colors=C ))
    lines.set_picker(2)
    lines.labels = L
    plt.show()

linecoll(10)
```

Output:

```
event
LineCollection
Which line did I clicked on ? 
[6]
event
LineCollection
Which line did I clicked on ? 
[5]
event
LineCollection
Which line did I clicked on ? 
[3 6]  # <- intersection
```

Note, if you click on an intersection of 2 lines, `event.ind` will contain the index of both `LineCollection`.